# Adding tasks that others depend on in one line

Tags: taskwarrior

Is there a way to add a task and specify that other tasks depend on this one in one line?? For example, I'm basically trying to do this:

```
task add proj:one Base task         # task 1
task add proj:one subtask1 blocks:1 # task 2
task add proj:one subtask2 blocks:2 # task 3
```

I know there is no `blocks` descriptor, but it would be nice if there were or if there's something like it.  Otherwise, my workflow is

```
task add proj:one Base task         # task 1
task add proj:one subtask1          # task 2
task 1 modify depends:2

task add proj:one subtask2          # task 3
task 1 modify depends:3
```

I know I can do:

```
task 1 modify depends:2,3
```

but I add these subtasks over time, so it ends up being two lines every time.  Is there any way to do it in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that so far works pretty great and does exactly what I was hoping for: https://gist.github.com/wbsch/a2f7264c6302918dfb30.

It's a hook that adds the `blocks:` attribute exactly as I described.  Thanks community!